# Add Mouse pointer on movieclip In Animate CC canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs, movieclip, mouse-cursor

I am trying to use a movieclip as a button, but the mouse cursor will not show on hover or on click...I have tried the answer on stack overflow, to add the movieClip.cursor = "pointer"; to the top of the code, but in my case there is no mouse pointer, (nor in Mozilla, nor in Chrome...)

In as 3.0 I used to use: buttonMode ="true", why does ..*.cursor = "pointer"* not work in canvas/html5...it is a simple code..?

here is my code

```
this.stop();
this.shape_mc.cursor = "pointer";

this.shape_mc.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler()
{
        this.play();
}
```

Comment: In case this is still relevant, have you set `enableMouseOver`? https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/MovieClip.html#property_cursor